# Is there a way to prevent change of data in unmodifiableList in the below scenario?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Here I have scenario where I want to create a unmodifiableList in such a way that no other part of the program can modify its initial values.

Here is the code snippet to give some idea about my problem.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> unmodifiableList = new ArrayList<String>();
        unmodifiableList.add("test1");
        unmodifiableList.add("test2");
        unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(unmodifiableList);
        List<String> modifiableList = new ArrayList<String>();
        modifiableList.addAll(unmodifiableList);
        unmodifiableList = modifiableList; 
        unmodifiableList.add("test3");
        for (String s : unmodifiableList) {
          System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
test1
test2
test3

Expected Output:
test1
test2

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: If you want it to be unmodufiable, why do you create a new modifiable list?

Comment: `unmodifiableList = modifiableList;` what you think this statement do?

Comment: This was just to demonstrate the problem here, but in actual application if some other developer can modify my unmodifiableList using the above way, then we can loose the sole purpose of making it unmodifiable.

Comment: check this out. https://www.baeldung.com/java-immutable-list

Comment: @Chamalee De Silva, thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below.

```
    final List<String> unmodifiableList1 = Collections.unmodifiableList(unmodifiableList);
```

to avoid creation of extra list try below.

```
final List<String> finalList = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("test1", "test2"));
```

Comment: this seems to be working but we need to create one extra list.

Comment: you can try this final List<String> unmodifiableList =Collections.unmodifiableList( new ArrayList<String>("test1", "test2")); to avoid creation of extra list

Comment: @ lion_pankaj, if you use this, final List<String> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList( new ArrayList<String>("test1", "test2"));, it will give you compilation error in eclipse, say "The constructor ArrayList<String>(String, String) is undefined".

Comment: yes, right, you can do following
final List<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("test1", "test2")));

Comment: This will work final List<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("test1", "test2")));